# Android calendar query URI android 4.0

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-calendar

All,

I am using the following URI path to query data for the calendar,

```
  1. content://com.android.calendar/calendars
  2. content://calendar/calendars
```

I read on blogs saying that these URI path wont be supportive on Android v4.0 and above.
It is only supportive from **2.1 - 2.3**
Can i know how can this be taken into consideration so i can incorporate the v4.0 and above  devices.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
`CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI`

CONTENT_URI contains calendar path. It supported by v4.0 or higher